# iphone application contains both Navigation Bar and Tab bar. With what i start creating my Project, SingleView app OR Tab bar based App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I am creating an application that contains the Use of both Navigation Bar along with Tab bar. For Some screens in the App we are not showing the tab bar. 
But most of the screens of the Applications are showing the Tab bar. 
So my question is with which option i should start to create my Project?
i.e With the single view Application OR with Tab-based Application. Also out of 30 pages of the application only 5-6 pages are there that are not showing the Tab bar. 
Apart from these all the screens are showing Tab bar.

So please suggest me an efficient and most useful way to start my project with. Also if i am creating my project with single view Application then how can i create an Tab bar with Navigation Bar with xib only. I don't want to use storyboard.

Also what if i start my application with Tab based and hide the tab bar for the pages that don't need to show.

Please someone suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a Tab Bar Controller to be present then It should be added as your root view, I suggest start with your Tab Bar Controller and embed that in a Navigation controller

EDit---

If you want to load the viewCOntroller first then You may have to add that to your window in your appdelegate

```
ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

now when you want to show your tabBarCOntroller through button then in the buttons IBAction just do this…

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{

```
    UIApplication *appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

 tabBarController= [[tabBarController alloc]init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@["your viewControllers"]];

UINavigationController *    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
    appdelegate.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [appdelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Is it possible to embed Tab Controller in Navigation Controller without Storyboard?
If not then can you please suggest me how can i do that with xib?

Comment: yes , select your Tab ViewController and then In your Xcode menu go to  Editor>Embed In>NavigationController or Use this in Your Code
 UINavigationController*  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
  
 self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Yes U are right.Also can u tell me that suppose i am on the viewcontroller. Now on the action of button click i want to move to the screen that consist of Tab bar. This tab bar screen is also of type UIViewController. Then what will be the hierarchy of the screens?

Comment: let me get this straight you want to navigate from 
UIViewcontroller-->TabBarController

Comment: Yes Exactly, that's i want

Comment: then you may have to toggle the views which you load in your window see do something like this..will add it to my answer ,just chk

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I will try it in my code and tell u the Result. Thanks again.